# Best way to declare variables in Node.js

Tags: node.js, coding-style, standards

Is it good to declare one variable per `var` statement, it makes code easier to re-order the lines in the program as per modification needs.

Could somebody make out, is there any difference between following style of declarations in Node.js in terms of execution of code?

```
//Style 1
var keys = ['foo', 'bar']; var values = [23, 42];

//Style 2
var keys = ['foo', 'bar'], values = [23, 42];
```

Comment: They are equivalent but the second has less typing (don't have to type var over and over).  Helpful for a block of variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have multiple `var` statements in JavaScript; this is called *hoisting*; However, because you can run into scoping issues, it's best to use a **single** declaration in any function.

It's common to see this style

```
var keys   = ['foo', 'bar'],
    values = [23, 42];
```

In fact, the very reason JavaScript allows you to chain the declarations together is because they should be happening together.

To illustrate a scoping issue:

```
f = "check?";

var hello = function () {
  console.log(f);          // undefined
  var f = "nope!";
  console.log(f);          // nope!
};

var hello2 = function () {
  console.log(f);          // check?
  var f2 = "nope!";        // not reusing `f` this time
  console.log(f2);         // nope!
};

hello();
hello2();
```

At first glance, you'd think the first output would be `check?`, but because you're using `var f` inside the function body, JavaScript is creating a local scope for it.

To avoid running into issues like this, I simply use a single `var` declaration :)